# how to play downloaded .mp4 video in videoview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

Is it possible to play 5 minutes long video(.mp4) in the android app?I just want some ideas and
solutions before I start the app so can you please help me to do this ?

Comment: First Google it than post your question

Comment: you can play the whole movie in android phone ...

Comment: or You can easily find the doc from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial. It will help you to build our app. 
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html

Comment: Thanks... first get an idea from this and do accordingly to your app